Power Apps collection function excel data table
I have a PowerApp where a user inputs data and it patches and updates an excel table. I need functionality that when the user is done (selects the done button), the excel table reverts back to its orignal values (disregards the users inputs).
What's the best method for this? I see something about making my data a collection, but idk how to do that.
Thanks!

You might want to check out SpreadsheetWeb API. It can expose your Excel file as a stateless calculation engine. I used it in the past in couple of projects. I recently saw an article related to connecting PowerAps to their API. If you are interested I'll see if I can find that article
